# How to mapped enum type to tinyint

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, enums, fluent

I'm just wondering. Is it possible in fluent api or anything that an `Enum` type would be mapped as `tinyint`?

Say for example,

```
public enum PaperType
{
  Rough=1,
  Smooth=2,
}

public class TestPaper
{
   public PaperType PaperType { get; set; }
}
```

And if run migration correctly, it will mapped to an `int` which is not I don't want. I want to assigned `tinyint` so that it would not take much as space. `int 4bytes` while `tinyint 1byte` Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do:

```
public enum PaperType : byte
{
  Rough=1,
  Smooth=2,
}
```

**But don't do that, that is premature optimization**. Only come to optimization like these if there is a problem in your application performance. *(default under laying type of `enum` is `int` so I am not sure if having a `byte` as enum type would save you anything, it will be treated as `int`. It might be useful if you are planning to use an array of `enum`, in that case you will get `byte[]`)*

Comment: Working solution for EF Core 1.1 as well

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that's what you are asking for:

```
public enum PaperType : byte
{
  Rough=1,
  Smooth=2,
}
```